# Conditional style using razor throws null exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following razor, but if I go directly to the url, it throws an null reference.  I looked at Request.Url.Host and none of those parts are null, what could be the problem:

```
@{
Layout = "NoNavigationMaster.cshtml";

var brand = Common.GetProductBrand(Request.Url.Host);

if (brand == BrandType.SCT)
{
   <style type="text/css">
               div.products-filter-overlay-body div.bg-image {
                   position: absolute;
                   height: 100%;
                   width: 100%;
                   bottom: 0;
                   top: 0;
                   left: 0;
                   right: 0;
                   background: url(overlay-bg@2x.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
                   background-size: cover;
               }
           </style>
}
else if(brand == BrandType.BullyDog)
{
     <style type="text/css">
                  div.products-filter-overlay-body div.bg-image {
                      position: absolute;
                      height: 100%;
                      width: 100%;
                      bottom: 0;
                      top: 0;
                      left: 0;
                      right: 0;
                      background: url(bd-products-filter-overlay-bg@2x.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
                      background-size: cover;
                  }
              </style>
}
}
```

Comment: What is your `Common.GetProductBrand()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the body of Common.GetProductBrand method it is difficult to tell. May be the razor @2x is null. Put a break point on them and inspect their values